# I want to tune a query that gets only the 1st in the ranking

Tags: mysql, row-number

row_number query question.

To get the data where rn is 1, you can wrap the query below and import it with where rn = 1.

Is there a way to get only those whose rn is 1 in the current query??

```
SELECT a1.member_no 
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.member_no ORDER BY a1.avg_hit_rate desc , a1.top_hit_cnt ) as rn
     , a1.join_no
FROM ht_typing_contents_join_log a1
WHERE a1.reg_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d' ) , '000000'), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
AND a1.reg_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d' ) , '235959'), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
and a1.success_yn = 'Y'
AND a1.len_type = '1'
```

Comment: Yes, the answer is exactly what you state in your question, you select from your query as a derived table *you can wrap the query below and import it with where rn = 1*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should subquery what you currently have and restrict to `rn = 1`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a1.member_no,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.member_no
                              ORDER BY a1.avg_hit_rate DESC, a1.top_hit_cnt) AS rn,
           a1.join_no
    FROM ht_typing_contents_join_log a1
    WHERE DATE(a1.reg_date) = CURDATE() AND
          a1.success_yn = 'Y' AND
          a1.len_type = '1'
)

SELECT member_no, join_no
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to get only the 1st in the ranking without using a subquery?

Comment: Because you have a partition, there would generally be more than one record having `rn = 1`.  What is your intention here?

Comment: *Is it possible to get only the 1st in the ranking without using a subquery?*, **No**. Currently windows function aren't supported in where clause

Comment: @ErgestBasha It isn't clear whether the OP maybe wants a limit query to just get one record (based on some ordering) or whether it wants what your comment describes.  Well...it _is_ possible to do this without a subquery on some databases.  SQL Server supports `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, and other databases (such as Teradata or BigQuery) support `QUALIFY`.  But MySQL supports neither of these.

Answer (score 0):

What I want is below.

```
SELECT a1. member_no
      , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.member_no ORDER BY a1.avg_hit_rate desc , a1.top_hit_cnt ) as rn
      , a1. join_no
FROM ht_typing_contents_join_log a1
WHERE a1.reg_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d' ) , '000000'), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
AND a1.reg_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d' ) , '235959'), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
and a1.success_yn = 'Y'
AND a1.len_type = '1'
AND rn = 1
```

Comment: No. Currently windows function aren't supported in where clause.

Comment: On some databases, you could add `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) = 1` after the `WHERE` clause and it would work...but MySQL does not support this.  You must use a subquery.